# Problems in understanding the while structure

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import sys

v_user = ""
v_pass = ""
v_lock  = ""

print "Unlock first "
v_lock = str(raw_input("> "))

while v_lock == "lock":
    print "Connected..."
    print "Enter user:"
    v_user = str(raw_input("> "))
    print "Enter password"
    v_pass = str(raw_input("> "))

    if v_user != "user1" or v_pass != "user1":
        print "Wrong user and password, try again..."
        print "Reconnecting.."
    else:
        print "Acces granted, system unlocked"
        sys.exit();

print "Wrong word for unlocking, exiting..."
```

So I have the above code and I don't understand well the `while` structure.

I don't know how to exit it only by using the `exit()` method. How it can be done in a more logical and cleaner manner?

How bad or how well is written the above piece?

Comment: You can remove all those semi-colons; Python doesn't need those.

Comment: `raw_input()` already returns a string, the `str()` calls are redundant.

Comment: Yeah you are right about semicolons, it's just a habbit like to know where the instruction ends and so on :)

Comment: I don't really understand the logic you are trying to implement, but a way that is commonly used to loop until some condition is met is to use `while True:` to essentially loop infinitely and then use `break` to escape the loop when you need to.

Comment: Neither do i, my logic is under-construction....hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than sys.exit(), you could just set v_lock to "" or anything other than 'lock'. The while loop will evaluate that as False then and will bypass the loop and pick up at:  'print "Wrong word for unlocking, exiting..."; '

Comment: I kinda still need the exit() to exit the while i noticed, because if i type "lock" it goes through all again and again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be done in better way in your code.

1) Follow the practice of having indentation of 4 spaces. That's the python indentation standard.

2) The raw input can take a string to be shown during input.Hence you can get rid of many print statements that are just redundant

3) As suggested by others, remove ';'. They are not required in python

4) Instead of using sys.exit(), set the value of v_lock to some other value, which will make the while loop condition false.

5) You need not declare or initialize the variables (v_lock, v_user and v_pass) at the beginning.

I formatted your code to look something like this:

```
v_lock = raw_input("Unlock first \n>")

while v_lock == "lock":
    print "Connected..."
    v_user = raw_input("Enter user:")
    v_pass = raw_input("Enter password:")
    if v_user != "user1" or v_pass != "user1":
        print "Wrong user and password, try again..."
        print "Reconnecting.."
    else:
        print "Acces granted, system unlocked"
        v_lock = "unlock"

print "Wrong word for unlocking, exiting..."
```

Hope this helps!